# Bootstrap 4 Safari Bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

See a stripped down version here: https://jsfiddle.net/dkmsuhL3/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
<title>Bootstrap Bug Test</title>
<!-- Bootstrap V4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000" />                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla fermentum felis sit amet augue luctus, at dignissim purus tristique. Etiam elit eros, varius ac tincidunt at, condimentum at felis. Integer eget ullamcorper ligula, ut finibus quam. Nunc tempor, enim id ultricies fringilla, ante risus venenatis ipsum, in euismod purus quam imperdiet libero. Ut diam lacus, tincidunt egestas tristique at, blandit quis est. Aenean bibendum sagittis ligula, sit amet mollis nisi iaculis at. Aenean blandit, mauris ac fermentum malesuada, massa arcu scelerisque arcu, quis molestie diam purus ut dolor.</p>
                <p>Praesent egestas placerat dui, ac mollis dolor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi sapien risus, consequat id tincidunt quis, lobortis a tortor. Morbi hendrerit tristique tempor. Vestibulum ultrices mauris magna, ac auctor lectus iaculis a. Aenean porta, nisi sit amet pellentesque fermentum, nibh ante molestie neque, non dictum ante justo sit amet dolor. Nunc scelerisque fringilla elit vitae tincidunt. Vivamus nec ex at enim aliquam tristique a in ipsum. Etiam bibendum mauris id scelerisque consequat. Donec nec orci leo. Nam ultricies condimentum porta. Mauris nunc nunc, ultricies in consequat sit amet, tristique ac lacus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I believe I have the syntax correct but the two col-sm-6 columns are not fitting horizontally on Safari (5.1.7)

[image: example]

Comment: If this is truly a bug I recommend you raise an issue in the [Github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues)

Comment: Thanks, done: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24647

Comment: Fixed all bootstrap 4 issues in safari: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234112/7186739

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug because the version of Safari to which you are referencing (5.1.7, Windows) is not supported by Bootstrap 4

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#desktop-browsers

In fact, support for that version of Safari expired in 2012, right around the time Apple ceased development of Safari for the Windows operating system and pulled Safari 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.1.7 is unsupported by Bootstrap.

That browser version doesn't fully support flexbox (only with `-webkit` prefix), and it doesn't support wrapping. You can try compiling on your own with larger Autoprefixer scope that will add `-webkit-` prefixes, or add them yourself by specifying.

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex; 
}
```

Unless other implementation bugs show up it might just work. But, you will have to use one row per, well, row, because of the `flex: wrap` not being supported.

P.S.
Unless your product has a significant percentage of audience that still uses that browser for some reason, it would make sense just to not worry about it. I suspect the usage will be close to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by searching on internet.

Bootstrap 4 is using `flexbox` property.  However, when I inspect `:before` and `:after` pseudo CSS elements' values are `table`.

So replace this with `flexbox`

```
 .clearfix:before,
 .clearfix:after, 
 .dl-horizontal dd:before, 
 .dl-horizontal dd:after, 
 .container:before, 
 .container:after, 
 .container-fluid:before, 
 .container-fluid:after, 
 .row:before, 
 .row:after{
      display: flex
 }
```